# Я увидел одну девчонку, красивую(,) по-моему, — Констанция

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

`Я увидел одну девчонку, красивую(,) по-моему, — Констанция.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я увидел одну девчонку, красивую по-моему, — Констанция* — вводное слово *по-моему* является частью обособленного определения и не отделяется от него запятой.

*Я увидел одну девчонку, красивую, по-моему, — Констанция* — вводное слово относится не к определению, а к одному из предшествующих членов предложения. Да, такую интонацию поначалу нелегко представить, но таки возможно.